# VB.NET : How to active html event on form

Tags: html, vb.net, forms, events

I've been blocking for a few days to activate event in **HTLM form with VB.NET**. I use the browser **Firefox with GECKO**. I manage to access in the website and put value in form but not to active the event.

I have two select box, one depending of the other.
For example : If a select value "Example 1" in select box 1, the select box 2 display "Answer 1A", "Answer 1B" ... Thus, if a select value "Example 2" in select box 1, the select box diplay "Answer 2A", "Answer 2B". This variation of choice is managed by an event.

For my program the id of select box 1 is : "Nature demande" and choice are "CPT", "CTR", "RES" ...
The id of select box 2 is : "type" and choice are "F175", "F180", "F200".

Unfortunately when I try to do this :
`CType(oFF.Document.GetElementById("natureDemande"), Gecko.DOM.GeckoSelectElement).Value="CTR"`

**The event does not trigger and so I have no choice for select box 2.** I can't select a value from my selection box 1 to activate the event.

I need your help to activate event and update choice of select box 2 with the value of the first.

I tried lot of things but some methods are out of date, and I don't understand the new approach.

Thank you so much for your help.